# How to return string value from the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
Alter procedure S_Comp(@str1 varchar(20),@r varchar(100) out)
as
declare  @str2 varchar(100)
set @str2  ='welcome to sql server. Sql server is a product of Microsoft'
if(PATINDEX('%'+@str1 +'%',@str2)>0)
    return @str1+'present in the string'
else 
    return @str1+'not present'
```

I am executing the above stored procedure. I am getting the following error :

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure S_Comp, Line 8 Conversion failed
>   when converting the varchar value 'Amruthanot present' to data type
>   int.

Please do help me resolving this

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are placing your result in the `RETURN` value instead of in the passed `@r`value.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx)

> *(RETURN)* 
>       Is the integer value that is returned. Stored procedures can return
>   an integer value to a calling
>   procedure or an application.

#### Changing your procedure.

```
ALTER procedure S_Comp(@str1 varchar(20),@r varchar(100) out) as 

    declare @str2 varchar(100) 
    set @str2 ='welcome to sql server. Sql server is a product of Microsoft' 
    if(PATINDEX('%'+@str1 +'%',@str2)>0) 
        SELECT @r =  @str1+' present in the string' 
    else 
        SELECT @r = @str1+' not present'
```

#### Calling the procedure

```
  DECLARE @r VARCHAR(100)
  EXEC S_Comp 'Test', @r OUTPUT
  SELECT @r
```

Comment: When i execute the above stored procedure I am getting following error:  Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure S_Comp, Line 0 Procedure or function 'S_Comp' expects parameter '@r', which was not supplied.

Comment: How do you execute the procedure?

Comment: DECLARE @r VARCHAR(100) EXEC S_Comp 'Test', @r SELECT @r But i am getting Null value now

Comment: I copied the above code what ter was written and executed it. But i got NULL value.

Comment: @Lieven... there is a correction. you need to mention OUT .... "EXEC S_Comp 'Test', @r out"

Comment: @Amrutha Perumal - I have fixed some errors in my code. That happens when typing from (failing) memory, sorry about that. Could you try the adjusted code?

Comment: @binil - you are right but it wasn't the only error. I had to SELECT @r instead of just assigning it.

Comment: Thanks alot...:-)I got the output.

Answer (score 8):

change your

```
return @str1+'present in the string' ;
```

to

```
set @r = @str1+'present in the string'
```

Comment: declare @i varchar(200)
 exec @i = S_Comp 'sql'
select @i

Comment: declare @i varchar(200) 
exec S_Comp 'sql', @i out
select @i

Answer (score 1):

Use SELECT or an output parameter.
More can be found here: 
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=100201

Comment: I have declared output parameter know.? but i am unable to return string value. Please do help me

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Is the integer value that is returned. Stored procedures can return an integer value to a calling procedure or an application.

Syntax
syntaxsql

RETURN [ integer_expression ]

it only returns integer values.